# Can Java 9 run on a 32-bit OS?

Tags: java, java-9

Seems there are no 32-bit download packages on 
Oracle's available [download list](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html).

**UPDATE**

Can download here:

```
wget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/9+181/jdk-9_windows-x86_bin.exe
```

Comment: In case anyone bumps into this question, looking for info on post Java 9 32-bit support... the AdoptOpenJDK project provides 32-bit binaries for Java 11, Java 12, Java 13.  Strangely, the project lacks 32-bit binaries for Java 9 and Java 10.  E.g. Java 13 https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk13&jvmVariant=hotspot#x32_win

Answer (score 59, accepted):

<strike>Although the 32-bit binaries for JDK9 seem to be missing from Oracle's lousy, unencrypted [download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), if (after clicking "Accept License Agreement") you copy the URL of the 64-bit binaries and change `x64` to `x86`, it will give you the 32-bit binaries.</strike>

---

Update: And now it's gone. Bizarre! What is Oracle playing at? They [went to the effort to fix x86-specific bugs for Java 9](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/issues/?jql=summary%20~%20x86%20AND%20Fixed%20%3D%20%229%22%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC), they [explicitly said 32-bit Windows and Linux were supported](https://web.archive.org/web/20170913215655/http://jdk.java.net/9/supported), they [list installation instructions for 32-bit systems](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-microsoft-windows-platforms.htm#JSJIG-GUID-61460339-5500-40CC-9006-D4FC3FBCFC0D), they [made 32-bit builds fully available throughout the pre-release period for testing purposes](https://web.archive.org/web/20170710132851/http://jdk.java.net/9/), and nothing in their [JDK 9 migration guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-7744EF96-5899-4FB2-B34E-86D49B2E89B6) indicates that 32-bit platforms have been dropped (quite the opposite in fact: it says the `-client` VM command line option has been dropped so the faster `-server` VM is now the default for 32-bit).

So why are they suddenly hiding the release binaries?

I happened to have downloaded the Windows JDK (including JRE) and the Linux JRE for x86. I don't have the Linux JDK. There's an Oracle digital signature in the properties of the Windows exe so you can see that it's genuine. I do hope Oracle get their act together.

- jdk-9_windows-x86_bin.exe: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B4RBD9LUbdlvUHpESXdEMmdudkE&export=download
  (SHA256: 62b9bc12ea64e9edb9950b0c784a1561b8503f7384270659ad93d66f1b3b456a)
- jre-9_linux-x86_bin.tar.gz: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B4RBD9LUbdlvb0dtOHR0eDVoQWc&export=download
  (SHA256: 372fbd6d8dc70c8087c0d3547f58d593266cf26cc4f6c6698b808930b3a4018a)
- jre-9_windows-x86_bin.exe
  (SHA256: bbd0e75dc6360e903dd905f080e1a1d76c9c78a27d9f7dd153c6e3adc6ebc78e)

---

Update 2: Apparently Oracle has decided to eliminate support for x86 Java forever. They somehow finished, compiled, digitally signed, and published the Java 9 binaries by accident. The binaries still work, but presumably will not receive updates.

---

Update 3: Apparently Oracle has become so hateful and hostile towards Java developers that they [have compelled Google to block the above downloads with a DMCA request](https://lumendatabase.org/notices/15112030). Nothing I can do. Sorry. If you have Java 9, you have it, and it will still work. If you don't have Java 9, well, you'll have to get creative.

Comment: No longer. Oracle removed x86 version. Do you still have a copy? Upload it please :)

Comment: They mention that they (as in Oracle) wont be shipping 32bit builds at a recent panel: https://youtu.be/Pr2v9E_oPXI?t=30m25s

Comment: @Boann I am very sorry to hear that... This JDK is so precious, keep it carefully :-)

Comment: Azul only certifies their 64-bit builds, but they do still have some newer 32-bit builds available for download.  https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/

Answer (score 6):

Chief Java Architect Mark Reinhold [in Twitter on September 25](https://twitter.com/mreinhold/status/912311207935090689):

> Sorry, but we have no plans to ship 32-bit builds of JDK 9. We’re
>   trying to focus more on the future than the past.
>
> Yes, you can build your own 32-bit JDK 9 binaries.

Comment: Sounds like somebody was told to cut costs.

Comment: and what about JavaFX? It cannot be built without a 32 bit version of Oracle JDK 9!

Comment: JavaFX is now gone too with JDK11+ ... I'm really starting to wonder what "focus more on the future than the past" really means

Comment: @FibreFoX - Incorrect.  It is not "gone".  The Oracle ["Future of JavaFX..."](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/the-future-of-javafx-and-other-java-client-roadmap-updates) announcement states that JavaFX will be available as a separate download starting in Java 11.  The stated reason is to make it easier for people to contribute to JavaFX.  Another reason is to allow the Java and JavaFX release cycles to be decoupled.

Answer (score 6):

I found a Win32 build here: https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild

This is a OpenJDK provided by RedHat (without support), no idea if they will provide those builds in future.

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle has dropped Windows 32-bit Client VM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-59701F80-5BB1-416D-835D-C39A9112FC1E)

However: The statement there "In JDK 9, the Windows 32–bit client VM is not available. Only a server VM is offered." is not even accurate, there is not even 32-bit server VM (as of Sep 27, 2017).

Update: Not just Windows, but no 32-bit for any platform is available.

[image]

Comment: This is not relevant to the missing 32-bit version of the platform.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by not relevant? My answer specifically said that neither the client nor the server VMs are available for 32-bit (Windows).

Comment: Suspension of support for 32-bit platforms refers to the -client option. Only the -server option is left.
As a matter of fact, I looked at the 64-bit version (1.8.0_141 for linux) -client also missing. While the 32-bit (1.8.0_144-b01 again for Linux) option is available.
Obviously, the 64-bit versions of -client have already been removed and are now removing 32-bit versions. But the very existence of the explanation of what is removed from the 32-bit platform is a sign that it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below link for openJDK, offers X86 (32bit) and X64 (64bit) for most java versions

https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk16&jvmVariant=hotspot

Answer (score -1):

Dropped Windows 32–bit Client VM: In JDK 9, the Windows 32–bit client VM is not available.

[data source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-59701F80-5BB1-416D-835D-C39A9112FC1E)

Comment: The statement there "In JDK 9, the Windows 32–bit client VM is not available. Only a server VM is offered." is not even accurate, there is not even 32-bit server VM.

Comment: If you read the ORACLE SOURCE I provided, it state "In JDK 9, the Windows 32–bit client VM is not available. Only a server VM is offered."

Comment: Yes it did state that. My point was that statement was not even accurate, most likely because Oracle changed minds after publishing that document.