# Which version of JRE for JDK 11?

Tags: java

What version of the jre is required for using jdk11?I can't find a jre version later than 8update192.

In general is a JDK version correlated to the Java language version? JDK 8 for Java 8 and JDK 11 for Java 11 ?

If I use JDK 11 can I run applications that use a lesser runtime for example 8? That is JDK 11 with Jre 8

Comment: You can find JRE 11 on https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html#JDK11 . Usually JREs are downwards compatible

Comment: **The JDK comes with the JRE**. You don't need a separate JRE installation to use a JDK.

Comment: *"is a JDK version correlated to the Java language version?"* Yes --- *"If I use JDK 11 can I run applications that use a lesser runtime"* Only if you explicitly tell the compiler to compile for older version, and don't use any new features.

Comment: Is Jre 11 a 64 bit runtime only? No 32 bits anymore?

Comment: See: [Can Java 9 run on a 32-bit OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46356345/5221149) --- And please stop asking new questions in a comment. If you have a new question, create a new Question.

Comment: Similar: [*How to get java 11 run-time environment working since there is no more jre 11 for download?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53111921/642706)

Answer (score 14):

> is a JDK version correlated to the Java language version?

Yes. The number of the kit to produce apps on the Java platform, the JDK, is numbered to match the version of Java platform. 8 for 8, 11 for 11, and so on.

> If I use JDK 11 can I run applications that use a lesser runtime for example 8? That is JDK 11 with Jre 8

You can use [JDK 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11) during development for earlier Java if your project is explicitly configured to be compiled and built for the earlier Java only.

Of course that means you cannot use features added in the later Java. But if your project is properly configured, your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) should prevent such features from being introduced into your codebase.

> What version of the jre is required for using jdk11?

There is no more separate JRE distribution. The JRE was a runtime-only environment used to run apps while the JDK was used to develop (and run) apps.

Now we have only JDK releases, as far as I know.

Oracle no longer intends for end-users to be installing a JRE or a JDK. [Java Applets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) in a browser and [Java Web Start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) app delivery are both being phased out, leaving the end-user with no need for a JRE. Java-based apps are expected to bundle their own Java implementation. The only folks consciously installing a JDK will be developers & server-side sysadmins.

Important:

- Understand clearly the nature of the [*OpenJDK*](http://openjdk.java.net) project, as [explained in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK).

  - Know that Oracle has committed to feature-parity between its own branded *Oracle JDK* and the *OpenJDK* project. This commitment includes donations of previously-commercial features such as [*Flight Recorder*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/328) and [*Mission Control*](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jmc/).
- Read this white paper by Oracle of 2018-03, [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdate2018mar-4414431.pdf)
- Read the white paper [*Java Is Still Free*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53112096/642706), authored by key members of the Java community.

Learn about:

- [*Java Platform Module System*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System)
- *jlink* ([JEP 282](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/282))
- *jpackage* ([JEP 343](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/343))

---

Here is a flowchart diagram that may help you finding and deciding amongst the various vendors providing a Java 11 implementation.

[image: Flowchart guiding you in choosing a vendor for a Java 11 implementation]

---

[image: Motivations in choosing a vendor for Java]