# Java 11 On Windows 7 32 bits

Tags: launch4j, java-11

I developed an Java application with Jdk 11 embedded. I packaged my application with launch4j and InnoSetup. 
I would like to run this application on 32-bit Windows 7. 
Is it possible to run it on 32 with an embedded Java 64?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't see how.  Java 64 implies a 64-bit OS.  Note that Oracle recommends you use the 32 bit runtime unless you have *enormous* data requirements.  See https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml.

Comment: Starting with Java 9 Oracle no longer provides 32 bits runtimes for Java (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46510935/5646962). If you must support 32-bit Windows you are stuck on Java 8.

Comment: My researches so far suggest that JDK-11 can be built for a 32-bit target but nobody has done so.  If you have a commercial need, a company like Azul might do the leg-work more efficiently than an in-house team working out how to do so.  If a private need (as mine is for an old linux netbook), do you fancy taking on the task?  There are links to instructions on the OpenJDK site, but you'll need libraries, a suitable set of compilers.

Answer (score 10):

The people from [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/index.html) took the burden of making builds for different architecture and as far as I can see there is a build for JDK 11 32bit version.

Check this [download page](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot#x32_win).