# Not able to run Hybris (Accelerator) server

Tags: java, cmd, sap-commerce-cloud, accelerator

Good morning! I am having some issues with hybris and I would really appreciate some advice from professionals with your expertise in the field.

I am using JDK 11.0.11 version and hybris 2011, I am able to build and setup successfully an accelerator but when I start the server I am getting the error below:

`FATAL | wrapper | The argument 'Files\---\CXCOMM201100P_7-70005693\hybris\bin\platform\tomcat/conf/wrapper.conf' is not a valid property name-value pair.`

Has anyone handled a similar error before? I would be so grateful if you could help me to solve it. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Given below are some probable reasons:

1. You have unzipped the pack in a folder that is very deep. Note that the Hybris folder structure goes very deep and if you unpack it already in a deep folder structure, you may face problems while building or running. I recommend you extract it under the root folder e.g. `D:\` e.g. in my Windows machine, I have extracted it directly in `C:\` and the structure is like `C:\CXCOMM201100P_7-70005693\...`
2. The folder to which you have extracted, has a whitespace character in its name.
3. You have unzipped using the default utility in Windows. This is one of the most common reasons in Windows machine. I suggest you use 7-Zip.
4. You are using an incompatible JDK build. SAP suggests using [SAP Machine](https://sap.github.io/SapMachine/).
5. It is rare but by any chance, you are using [32-bit JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53786500/10819573).

Using a Zip utility like 7-Zip, extract the pack into a root directory or at least a directory that is no deeper than two levels and does not have a whitespace character in its name. Also, use a compatible JDK build.

Comment: Thank you @Arvind, I will try to do everything you said and then I will come back to give you feedback. Thanks.