# Running JMS on staggered JDK versions

Tags: java, jms, java-11

Since Oracle has gone out of their way to [obliterate all support for 32-bit OSs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46371775/5874459).

I'm faced with the issue where I have to update my server-side Java version to 11. However, I can't upgrade my client since it needs to support 32 bit systems.

What are some of the issues with running this environment in a staggered fashion?
Where the JMS client is Java 8 and the server is Java 11.

Now before this is marked as too broad, there's very little information I could obtain about this via Google searches and it can become a common concern with Oracle dumping 32-bit support without any outright announcement. However, I do concede I'm trying to save up some time here.

Comment: Sockets are the same on every OS. Since JMS uses sockets, you should be fine unless you have to upgrade the JMS implementation on the server (as in: You suddenly need ActiveMQ X on the server because version Y doesn't support Java 11 but the clients are stuck with Y.

Comment: @AaronDigulla, for what it's worth JMS is an API and the specification doesn't mention anything about sockets. Implementers are free to use whatever technology they like. It wouldn't matter in this case, but there are lots of transport implementations for intra-jvm clients which don't use sockets.