# Java 11 JDK for Windows 7 32-bit system

Tags: java, windows-7, java-11, 32-bit

I wanted to install Java 11 on my Windows 32-bit System.

I've searched [this Official Java 11 Download Page](https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html) doesn't contain any download for a 32-bit system.

[image: ![image|690x451](upload://eydqHMGEHusQpITxQz268orsb7p.png)]

But still I didn't lose my hope, I saw [this site](https://adoptium.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk11)

[image]

But when I saw the `2012r2`, I think it won't work for my **2009** Windows 7 32-it system, but anyways its a different version than Java Official one.

I even saw [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46356345/can-java-9-run-on-a-32-bit-os/46510935#46510935)

It is about Java 9 but even though I don't think the command (which is in the 1st post) doesn't work (I haven't tested it yet).

Comment: Please don't fill your question with emojis and your feelings. This is not Facebook.

Comment: (1/2) Regarding "Urgent/ASAP" (source: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140476/need-to-store-a-2d-list-but-not-using-array#comment52170418_32140476)): "You would be wise not to state this in your posts. Even if it is urgent to you, realize that it is not urgent to us. Many here take offense to this as it implies to them that a) the poster thinks that his post is more important than everyone else's (and it isn't since **all** questions here are equally important), and b) that the poster wants to put pressure on the volunteers who come here to help on their own free time."

Comment: (2/2) Also please see: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: Ok! I will follow these from the next time...

Comment: Since the https://adoptium.net/ allows you to select Window 32 bit, why don’t you download and try to install that version? Perhaps, it still works even if not officially supported. You don’t know if you don’t try.

Comment: Sure @Holger I will try installing it

Answer (score 5):

You won't find an Oracle supported release for Java 11 on 32bit Windows.  Oracle stopped distributing 32 bit Java builds for Windows after Java 8.

According to https://bell-sw.com/pages/supported-configurations/  Liberica Java 8, 11 and 17 are available for 32 bit Desktop Windows and supports Window 7 SP1, Windows 8 and Windows 10.

There may be other alternatives too.

However.  Windows 7 is [nearly 2 years beyond end-of-life](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/windows-7-end-of-life-support-information).  You should have upgraded your system.

Comment: Thanks for you reply @Stephen C

Actually, I couldn't update as its a pirated version

Comment: So ... pay for a genuine version ... or replace it with Linux ... which is free.  Trying to do Java development on an ancient OS and (probably) ancient hardware is just asking for problems.

Comment: @B.S.S.SRIKAR did you actually try to update?

Comment: (Or ... buy a new machine with a genuine copy of Windows 11 included in the price.)

Answer (score 2):

There are other ways we can use JAVA 11 for 32-bit OS, there are some 3rd party website which has been confirmed by JAVA community provides JAVA 11 for 32-bit

As an example Amazon Corretto. Follow the below link for more details

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-11-ug/downloads-list.html

Comment: *"... 3rd party website which has been confirmed by JAVA community ..."* - This doesn't mean anything.  The key thing is to download the distro from the >>distro vendor's website<<.  You can validate that by checking the website's certificate in your web browser.  There are a number of reputable 3rd-party Java vendors / distributors.  But the "Java community" is not a thing that can "confirm" a website or a vendor.  (Anymore that the "Java community" can "confirm" Oracle or its websites.)

Comment: And ... it is Java not JAVA.  Java is not an acronym.